# Error on terminal while adding pod - [!] Invalid Podfile file: The target Pods-MyApp already has a platform set

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoapods

In my app i have integrated **Googlemap** using **CocoaPod**.

Now I want to integrate **CitrusPay** using **CocoaPod** but when i have execute pod install command on terminal then i am getting error - 
[!] Invalid **Podfile** file:

The target **Pods-MyApp** already has a platform set..

from /Users/NewFolder/Desktop/xyz.app.MyApp.ios/Podfile:10

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
platform :ios, '8.1'
pod 'GoogleMaps'
```

Does anyone knows how to solve this error?

Comment: Just use "pod update" instead of "pod install" and check if it works, let me know

Comment: @Janmenjaya I have also tried pod update command but getting same error

Comment: can you  show your terminal screenshot what are you doing ?

Comment: @balkaransingh i m getting error -
Savitas-Mac-mini:ufony.app.schooldiary.ios Savita$ pod install

[!] Invalid `Podfile` file: The target `Pods-School Diary` already has a platform set..

 #  from /Users/Savita/Desktop/Savita/CitrusIntegration/Using CocoaPod/ufony.app.schooldiary.ios/Podfile:10
 #  -------------------------------------------
 #      source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
 >      platform :ios, '8.1'
 #      pod 'GoogleMaps'
 #  -------------------------------------------
Savitas-Mac-mini:ufony.app.schooldiary.ios Savita$

Comment: Try one way, remove the pods from your pod file, then add the again. May be that help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i have the same question with you,and than search answer in the internet,but nothing ,so i solve question myself,
step:
first  :  sure you 'Podfile' file only have "platform:ios,'version'" one time;
second :  add "target 'yourtarget'do" in the file top;
third  :  add "end" in the file bottom.

you must maintain your "Podfile" file have formatter:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TCXvX.png)

you will solve this question, wish can help you.thanks.

Comment: Thanks, But i have already solve that issue.
My issue was i have declare "platform:ios,'version'" two(2) times.

Answer (score 1):

Add target to your podfile

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
platform :ios, '8.1'

target 'YourTarget' do
   pod 'GoogleMaps'
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and eventually I solved it, now my Podfile looks like this

```
#Alamofire - lib for HTTP requests
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
platform :ios, '10.0'
use_frameworks!

target 'Fitzz' do
pod 'Alamofire', '~> 4.0'

#XCGLogger - lib for loggin output
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
platform :ios, '8.0'
use_frameworks!

pod 'XCGLogger', '~> 4.0.0'

end
```

I am a rookie in iOS, but this works for me